# Random.Range в Unity 5

Tags: c#, unity3d

Метод Random.Range() с интервалом от 0 до 1 у меня почему-то совсем не работает.

Вот код, и ниже результат его выполнения:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100;i++ )
{
    Debug.Log(Random.Range(0, 1));
}
```

[image: Результат выполнения кода]

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

У метода [`Random.Range`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html) 2 варианта: `float Random.Range(float min, float max)` и `int Random.Range(int min, int max)`. В вашем случае вы передаёте 2 `int`'а, поэтому используется перегрузка, возвращающая `int`. Так как `Random.Range` возвращает числа из интервала `[min, max)`, единственное целое число, которое он может вернуть - 0. Чтобы возвращались действительные числа из интервала `[0, 1)`, нужно передавать в метод `float`'ы:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100;i++ )
{
    Debug.Log(Random.Range(0f, 1f));
}
```