# Random.Range() возвращает одно и тоже число. (unity/c#)

Tags: c#, unity3d

Почему Random.Range() возвращает одно и тоже число?
Каждый раз он возвращает 0.

```
Instantiate(Object[Random.Range(0, 1)], new Vector2(0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
```

Comment: `Random.Range(0.0f, 1.0f)`

Comment: целочисленный max в Random.Range исключается

Comment: Есть уже такой вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/429239/random-range-%D0%B2-unity-5

Comment: Блин, теперь число равняется от 0f до 1f. Допустим 0.342f, а надо либо 0 либо 1

Comment: `Random.Range(0, 2)` же, ну)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Random.Range в Unity 5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/429239/random-range-%d0%b2-unity-5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы получать случайные нули и единицы, нужно вызывать:

```
Random.Range(0, 2) // integers in range [0, 2)
```

В целочисленной перегрузке Random.Range max исключается:

> `public static int Range(int min, int max);`

> **Description**:
> Return a random integer number between min [inclusive] and max [exclusive]
>
> Note max is exclusive. Random.Range(0, 10) can return a value between
> 0 and 9. Return min if max equals min.

[Документация](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html)

> **Описание**:
> Возвращает случайное целое число между min [включительно] и max [исключительно]
>
> **Внимание**: max не включается. `Random.Range(0, 10)` может возвращать значения от 0 до 9. Возвращает min, если max равен min.

Итак, Вам нужен `Random.Range(0, 2)`

---

<sub>Перегрузка для действительных чисел, напротив, включает оба конца интервала.</sub>

Comment: Спасибо огромное! В юнити перешел с питона, а в питоне random.randint(0,1), действительно возвращает 0 либо 1.

Answer (score 1):

Дополню, если нужно от 0.5f и до 4 то вот вам пример.

```
Random.Range(.05f,4);
```